# Enum has not been declared

Tags: c++, enums

I use the following header `Node.h`:

```
/*
    INCLUDE PROTECTION
*/
#ifndef NODE_H_INCLUDED
#define NODE_H_INCLUDED

/*
    Include
*/
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
//#include "NodeConnection.h"
#include "Tile.h"
#include "Network.h"

/*
    Declarations
*/
class Network;
class NodeConnection;

class Node {
    private:

        Tile* tile;

        std :: vector <NodeConnection*> connections;
        std :: unordered_map <Node*, NodeConnection*> connectionmap;

    public:

        /* Enumeration */

        enum NAVIGATION {
            RIGHT = 0, 
            UP = 1, 
            LEFT = 2, 
            DOWN = 3
        };

        Node (Tile* _tile);

        void FindNeighbours(Board* board, Network* network);

        void SetNodeConnection(Node* node, NodeConnection* nodeconnection);

};

struct TileNavigation {
    Tile* tile;
    enum Node :: NAVIGATION navigation;
};

#endif
```

And the following in the header of `NodeConnection.h`:

```
/*
    INCLUDE PROTECTION
*/
#ifndef NODECONNECTION_H_INCLUDED
#define NODECONNECTION_H_INCLUDED

/*
    Include
*/
#include <string>
#include "Node.h"

/*
    Declarations
*/
class Node;
struct Nodes;


enum ConnectionType {
    WALLCONN, PATHCONN, UNKNOWN
};

class NodeConnection {
    private:

        enum ConnectionType contype;

        struct Nodes;

    public:

        //NodeConnection ();
        NodeConnection (Node* a, Node* b,  NAVIGATION initial_nav);
};

struct Nodes {

    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    std :: string steps;

};

#endif
```

I have tried `Node :: NAVIGATION` and `NAVIGATION`, but yet it keeps telling me that

```
"   'NAVIGATION' has not been declared   "
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for pointers.

Comment: Node::NAVIGATION should work...

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) there is some detail missing in your sample code, using `Node::NAVIGATION` [should work see live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38b1ce66e5f99f30).

Comment: `NodeConnection (Node* a, Node* b,  Node :: NAVIGATION initial_nav);` does not work, it gives the same error

Comment: Yes, so can you provide an SSCCE? There is no way to tell what the problem is from the code given.

Comment: `Node::NAVIGATION` works as is, so you're not telling us some important detail.  for example, is `Node` declared within a namespace?

Comment: Actually I wrote it right now with `Node::NAVIGATION` and it worked.

Comment: Perhaps in the class definition of Node, there is a `private:` somewhere preceding the enum?  Although I would think that would lead to a different error message.

Comment: Your code is correct. That means either your compiler is broken, or this is not your real code. Please, try to compile the code you actually posted and see if it works.

Comment: added the full classes, have I made an error somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your have `circuit-include` issue. `Node.h` and `NodeConnection.h` include each other.

To fix:

Forward declare `Nodeconnection` in `Node.h`, remove `#include "NodeConnection.h"` from Node.h to break `circuit-including` issue.

```
//#include "NodeConnection.h"  // 
class Network;
class NetworkConnection; // forward declare NetworkConnection
class Node {
//..
};
```

include `NodeConnection.h` in Node.cpp file.

```
#include "NodeConnection.h"
```

use `Node::NAVIGATION` in NodeConnection.h

```
class NodeConnection {
private:

    //enum ConnectionType contype;  don't need to use enum keyword again.
    ConnectionType contype;

public:

    //NodeConnection ();
    NodeConnection (Node* a, Node* b,  Node::NAVIGATION initial_nav);
```

};

Comment: It has not fixed the issue :S Thanks for the advice though

Comment: Thanks, that does work. But now it indicates an error in invalid use of incomplete type 'class NodeConnection' ><

Comment: #include "NodeConnection.h" in Node.cpp file